# How to Recreate this in LaTeX? (Unsure What the Notation is Called)

Tags: automata

How would I produce a diagram like this in LaTeX? It's from my book, and I'd like to be able to answer the questions from the section in this format.

[image: ⊢ notation maybe]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can do that very easily with `tikz-cd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bernard says, it can be done with `tikz-cd`. (@Bernard: saying something of that sort doesn't mean I didn't know that, of course I did, but it is IMHO nicer to acknowledge comments that go in the same direction as an answer that one is going to post.) You need to move the commas and so on yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
\tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style = {-latex}}
\[  \begin{tikzcd}
(q_0,111,Z_0)  \ar[dr] \ar[d]&    &  \\
(q_0,111,Z_0)  \ar[dr] \ar[d]& (q_1,111,Z_0)\ar[r]  & (q_2,111,Z_0)  \\
(q_0,111,Z_0)  \ar[dr] \ar[d]& (q_1,111,Z_0)\ar[r]  & (q_2,111,Z_0) \ar[d] \\
(q_0,111,Z_0)  \ar[dr] \ar[d]& (q_1,111,Z_0) \ar[dr] & (q_2,111,Z_0)  \\
(q_0,111,Z_0)  \ar[d]& (q_1,111,Z_0)\ar[d]  & (q_2,111,Z_0) \ar[d] \\
(q_0,111,Z_0)  & (q_1,111,Z_0)  & (q_2,111,Z_0) \ar[d] \\
  &  & (q_2,111,Z_0)  \\
  \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly the same as the one on page 188 of Comp 335 by David Ford down the road from you ? at Concordia Montreal but it proves you can convert pdftex to pdf to png to html to tex to pdfLaTeX to html without a loss in quality or a single pandoc step in sight :-)

Comment: @KJO I probably need another day or so to understand this one. ... ;-)

Comment: Just that the original written in Montreal Uni was obtained by OP as PDF they converted to PNG on this web page You rewrote the tex ….. and all done by hand or paw

Comment: @KJO Claws. Marmots have claws.

Comment: OK consider my wrists slapped